# Should I use sync two databases by using only incremental files, os should I use a combination of incremental + full sync (at the end of every month)

Tags: database, multiple-databases, bulk-load, delta

I have a table present in my system which needs to be in sync with a third party table at a daily interval. The table size is >50 million rows and every day, around < 1% gets updated/created and hence we perform incremental sync where they send the delta data to us every day. Now, this is based on timestamps and I was wondering whether we should have monthly full data sync to make sure everything is in order. I'm guessing this will act as a validation of sorts to confirm that any data that is missed during the daily, will be sent in the monthly.

The full data sync is obviously painful to do (how do you easily update 50 million rows in your relational database) but assuming that that is feasible, should incremental data syncs really be backed up by monthly full syncs to ensure full data sync, or is this just over-engineering a simple problem which should work off the bat?

EDIT: It is not a db replication and we do a few modifications on a few columns in the source data as well as add a few custom attributes of our own to each row.

Comment: Just for checking if everything is working fine I would generate a hash over the data on both systems and compare it.

Comment: It's not db replication. We use completely different database structures itself.